# Describing C3 in terms of predicates on types

Tags: object-oriented

What is the right way to describe the properties for a method resolution order that naturally lead you to the C3 linearization algorithm?

*I'm trying to nail down desiderata for an MRO that are* conceptually prior *to the C3 algorithm itself.*

I recently read a blog post on C3 resolution order and its use in Python [here](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html).

The post talks about C3 satisfying a monotonicity property and informally describes an invariant that we'd like to hold for the system as a whole.

> Within a complex inheritance hierarchy, you want to be able to satisfy
>   all of these possible rules in a way that is monotonic. That is, if
>   you have already determined that class A should be checked before
>   class B, then you should never encounter a situation that requires
>   class B to be checked before class A (otherwise, the result is
>   undefined and the inheritance hierarchy should be rejected).

We can take that (section of a) paragraph and run with it. We define two predicates:

- $A < B$ means $A$ is a subclass of $B$ and $A \neq B$
- $A \sqsubset B$ means $A$ is checked before $B$ and $A \neq B$

And then we start coming up with rules (101-104). $(A \;\text{extends}\; B,C)$ is meant to be interpreted fact about the source code, not a new predicate. (I don't know if it's valid to draw a distinction like that). The other thing I'm doing that's a little weird is creating a partial order out of a $<$-like and $=$-like predicate instead of just a $\le$-like one, but I think the meaning is clear.

$$ (<, =) \;\;\; \text{ is a partial order} \tag{101} $$

$$ (\sqsubset, =) \;\;\; \text{is a partial order} \tag{102} $$

$$ \frac{A < B}{A \sqsubset B} \tag{103} $$

$$ \frac{(A \;\text{extends}\; B, C)}{A < B \;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\; A < C \;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\; B \sqsubset C} \tag{104} $$

However, from these facts we can immediately tell that (105) should be rejected as invalid since $E \sqsubset F$ and $F \sqsubset E$ cannot simultaneously be true.

$$ (A \;\text{extends}\; E, F) \;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\; (B \;\text{extends}\; F, E) \implies \bot \tag{105} $$

However, the equivalent Python 3+ (106) will run without producing any errors:

```py
class E: pass         # (106)
class F: pass
class A(E, F): pass
class B(F, E): pass
```

In order to get Python to complain about the method resolution order, we actually have to inherit from both $A$ and $B$ simultaneously (107).

```py
class E: pass      # (107)
class F: pass
class A(E, F): pass
class B(F, E): pass
class Z(A, B): pass
```

produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inherit.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Z(A, B): pass
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases E, F
```

This immediately raises some questions:

- Is (106) actually "invalid" in some sense and Python simply doesn't reject it?
- Do we want to replace $\sqsubset$ with a three-place predicate that captures "where we're resolving methods from"?